# Style from .css doesn't work. What's wrong?

Tags: html, css

In my `project.css` I have 2 similar classes. There is no difference between them except name of the classes.

```
.eventsimgmain {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.dormimg {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

In my html file I have two images:

```
<img class="eventsimgmain" src="../../static/img/dorm1.JPG">
<img class="dormimg" src="../../static/img/dorm2.JPG">
```

So, `.eventsimgmain` is the same as `.dormimg`. It puts image to the center of my `<div>`. The problem is that the second class (`.dormimg`) doesn't work. I expect these classes to work the same, but `.dormimg` does NOTHING. Why? I turned off a server, I saved all changes to the project.
[Here is how it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWZwp.png)

[Here is a 1 image. Everything is fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7dEC.png)

[Here is 2 image. And here is where problem is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmNYa.png)

[This is a screenshot of project.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVJNZ.png)

Comment: What do you mean the second class *"doesn't work"*? Either you're sharing an incomplete example with us, or have incorrect expectations. Please edit your question to **(1)** explain what you expect vs what is actually happening, and **(2)** include a minimal example that *reproduces the issues*.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with the code you've provided. You need to supply a [mcve] (emphasis on the Verifiable)

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example or share a plunker to display the issue. Your classes should be working fine unless the second one is overridden by another class having same name.

Comment: Try right clicking on the incorrect img and inspecting it with your browser inspector.  That will tell you if a CSS rule is being overridden.

Comment: dmikester1, i checked both images in my browser. There is a CSS rule for first image, (class eventsimgmain from project.css). Second image doesn't have a CSS rule from project.css

Comment: Well, that is your answer.  Figure out why it's not getting the CSS rule applied from project.css.

Comment: dmikester1 Well, this is my question

Comment: The code you posted above works perfect as Quentin verified.  You must have a spelling mistake or something in your code.  There is no reason it shouldn't work if you have the same code as above.  Are you missing a period before the class name?

Comment: Very odd indeed.  In your screenshot that says "Here is 2 image. And here is where problem is", you see where it has a link to project.css?  That is the version it is actually using.  Click on that link and verify it is what you expect.  It might be using a cached version.

Comment: Why do you say the first class is working? That `.eventsimgmain` image doesn't appear to be centered to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: dmikester1 actually, there was a wrong screenshot. i've updated my screenshots

Comment: Those look like the same screenshots

Comment: Ryan, [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmNYa.png)

Comment: Sorry dude, I'm not clicking that.

Comment: Inspect the other image and what do you see in the inspector?

Comment: Ryan, if you not clicking the link, update this page. there was a mistake with screenshots

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that your `.dormimg` class is being overwritten by some other style that is being applied to that type of element. Right click on the element and use the Inspector tool and look in the **STYLES** sidebar to verify.

Comment: .dormimg cannot be owerwritten because there is only one example of this class. Please check my second and third image in the question above